# window.open not working for _self

Tags: javascript, jquery

Kindly take a look at my following js function. The function works fine if i do the redirection without _self attribute. Also no matter what I did its not stopping the redirection the page itself I think that's why the `_self` not working and works fine for `_blank`.

```
function checkcat()
    { 
    if ($(".caty").find(".active-cat").length > 0){ 
window.open("http://www.google.com","_self");

// window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank");
}
else
{
alert('Aloha!!!');
// Following I used to strictly stop the redirection but it didnot work :(
stopPropagation();
preventDefault();
return false;

}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the page from submitting, you need to do it like this:

```
function checkcat() { 
    if ($(".caty").find(".active-cat").length > 0){ 
      window.open("http://www.google.com","_self");
    } 
    else {
      alert('Aloha!!!');
    }

    return false;
}
```

Only `return false` will do the job. In your method, you do not pass in the `event` object and calling `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` ***will throw exception as there are no such methods***.

If you call `checkcat` inside form submit, remember to include the `return` to stop the form from submitting:

```
<form onsubmit="return checkcat()">
</form>
```